# Unable to retrieve profile information after user logs in to my website with Google sign in

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google sign in, in my website. I followed the instructions give on the  page [Google sign in page.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) I properly set the client ID and after creating the project following the instructions given. The sign in page is showing up properly and asking me to give permissions to the application to access the basic profile and email details. Once I click accept, I am not able to retrieve the user profile details and print to the console in the javascript function that gets called after a successful login. The following is the code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        console.log("console works");
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };

    </script>



  </body>
</html>
```

I have removed the client id in the code posted above for privacy reasons, but in the actual implementation I have included it.

Comment: Can you try to put `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>` at the bottom of body?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understandable with your code

But try this code. Its working fine for me

Include it in `<head>` tag

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
  </script>
  </head>
```

Include it in `<Body>`

```
<body>    
<button class="g-signin " 
                        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
                        data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
                        data-clientId="----YOUR CLIET ID----"
                        data-accesstype="offline"
                        data-callback="mycoddeSignIn"
                        data-theme="dark"
                        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
                    </button>
</body>
```

and the script for retrieving the data

dont for get to add this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gpclass = (function(){

//Defining Class Variables here
var response = undefined;
return {
    //Class functions / Objects

    mycoddeSignIn:function(response){
        // The user is signed in
        if (response['access_token']) {

            //Get User Info from Google Plus API
            gapi.client.load('plus','v1',this.getUserInformation);

        } else if (response['error']) {
            // There was an error, which means the user is not signed in.
            //alert('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
    },

    getUserInformation: function(){
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} );
        request.execute( function(profile) { 
            var email = profile['emails'].filter(function(v) {
                return v.type === 'account'; // Filter out the primary email
            })[0].value;
            var fName = profile.displayName;
            console.log(fName);
            console.log(email);
        });
    }

}; //End of Return
})();

function mycoddeSignIn(gpSignInResponse){
    gpclass.mycoddeSignIn(gpSignInResponse);
}
</script>
```

Check on console the data will be their.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the sign in page is showing up but the function onSignIn() is never reached.
I tried with several other ways, like with a custom sign-in button, but I got the same problem.

May be there is some problem in the Google Developers Console?
I have Google+ API enabled.